# If a Pokemon is caught by multiple people, is it the same Pokemon with the same IVs/stats?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have tried it three times, and that seem to the case: the CP and HP are different because the two players are at different levels and one Pokemon has a low CP like 10 or 14, and the other Pokemon has a high CP such as 384.

But if I check for the IV and Perfection of the CP 384 Pokemon, it gave me one number, and if I spend stardust and candies to power up the CP 10 Pokemon, I do get the same Perfection number as the other player's Pokemon.

So are they the same Pokemon with the identical IV and Perfection number?  If that is the case, one way we can save stardust and candies is to catch 2 or 3 Pokemons by 3 players, and then just run through the IV calculator using "Calculate" for the first Pokemon, and use "Refine" for the other 2 Pokemons. Then in this case, we may be able to save stardust which sometimes would be 3000 or 3500 stardust.

Answer (score 9):

While [Kaz Wolfe's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282751/162442) may have been true at one point, it is no longer the case. While with friends today, we found a Bayleef. All three of us caught the Bayleef, but each Bayleef had different appraisal results.

[image: my bayleef]

[image: bayleef 2]

[image: bayleef 3]

Thus, not only were the Bayleef's levels different, they had much different IVs, as well.

Comment: This is the new behaviour as of a recent update, presumably to combat spoofers who acquired rare high IV Pokemon by falsifying their location. [Source](http://pokemongoinformer.com/pokemon-go-update-makes-cheating-harder/)

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes or to be accepted so it can be the first answer.  I am interested in whether any of you 3 were the same level when catching this, though.

Answer (score 8):

> ***Note:*** As Niantic has altered their game and allowed it to evolve, this answer is no longer accurate for current versions of the game. Please see [Vemonus' answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/308966/76693) for the up to date version. This answer exists for archival purposes only.

When a Pokemon spawns, every person who catches it gets the exact same IV Pokemon.

The difference you're noting with CPs and Levels is because the game will only give the exact same Pokemon to two people with the same level. Otherwise, the Pokemon's Level will be somewhat randomized.

As these Pokemon are all equivalent by IV, you can calculate IVs using each unique Pokemon caught as a single data point, although you may not actually get an exact value with these data points in mind.

Similarly, one of the key features of most algorithms is the "leveling" method. Some algorithms will spit back at this problem, but others should work without much issue.

Comment: Do you have the source for the research?

Comment: @Nelson My entire office (about seven players) corroborated these with about 50+ Pokemon. That, in addition to spawn data by a few (defunct) research bots taken down in accordance with Niantic's wishes.

Comment: Do they also have the same move set?

Comment: This fact is not true for me at all. Me and my brother are on same level in pokemon go and we have never got same CP pokemon ever till now. There is always a difference of minimum about 50CP.

Comment: @VivekMishra We know that. The IV is the same, the CP is not always the same.

Comment: This may have been true at one point, but it is no longer the case

Comment: This has been changed in a recent update, presumably to combat spoofers who acquired rare high IV Pokemon by falsifying their location. [Source](http://pokemongoinformer.com/pokemon-go-update-makes-cheating-harder/)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to break it down..

IV's and moves are the same if catching the exact pokemon as another person did. However the CP can vary but doesn't mean it will. If you are playing with 2-3 people in the same vehicle and all are above level 30, you will have a chance to be synced to the same server and catch the exact same pokemon (encounters in the wild do not pass level 30 in trainer level) However if you have a level 20 trainer and a level 35 trainer playing, and the pokemon happens to be "trainer level 27" the trainer level 35 will catch the pokemon at the maxed level that the server has for that particular spawn of that pokemon, while the level 20 trainer will have a reduced pokemon down to the trainer level (level 20). Also, if you notice that the person next to you or playing with you is on the same server and they are a higher trainer level than you and a pokemon spawns that is maxed for his level but not yours, if close enough you can level up and click on that pokemon again and it will have a higher CP.